# Asmx web service basic authentication

Tags: web-services, asmx, basic-authentication

I want to implement basic authentication using username and password validation in my **asmx** web service.
**I don't want to use WCF and I know this is not secure way**, but I need to use basic authentication without using https.

My web service is like this:

```c#
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.mywebsite.com/")]
public class Service1
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello world";
    }
}
```

And I use this custom HttpModule:

```c#
public class BasicAuthHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    void IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.AuthenticateRequest += new EventHandler(OnAuthenticateRequest);
    }

    void OnAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string header = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

        if (header != null && header.StartsWith("Basic"))  //if has header
        {
            string encodedUserPass = header.Substring(6).Trim();  //remove the "Basic"
            Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
            string userPass = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encodedUserPass));
            string[] credentials = userPass.Split(':');
            string username = credentials[0];
            string password = credentials[1];

            if(!MyUserValidator.Validate(username, password))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //send request header for the 1st round
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            context.Response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", String.Format("Basic realm=\"{0}\"", string.Empty));
        }
    }

    void IHttpModule.Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

And in the web.config I use this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
        <authentication mode="None"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <add name="BasicAuthHttpModule"
                 type="AuthService.BasicAuthHttpModule, AuthService" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The calling code is:

```c#
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var proxy = new Service1.Service1()
                    {
                        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user1", "p@ssw0rd"),
                        PreAuthenticate = true
                    };
    try
    {
        var result = proxy.HelloWorld();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

when I use this web service, the service asks for basic authentication but `header` variable in the `OnAuthenticateRequest` method always is null and     `MyUserValidator.Validate()` never run.

**EDIT**

The fiddler results:

```
POST http://www.mywebsite.com/Service1.asmx HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 2.0.50727.4927)
VsDebuggerCausalityData: uIDPo+drc57U77xGu/ZaOdYvw6IAAAAA8AjKQNpkV06FEWDEs2Oja2C+h3kM7dlDvnFfE1VlIIIACQAA
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://www.mywebsite.com/HelloWorld"
Host: www.mywebsite.com
Content-Length: 291
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 

xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><HelloWorld xmlns="http://www.mywebsite.com/" /></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=""
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="www.mywebsite.com"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 03 Jun 2012 07:14:40 GMT
Content-Length: 1293
------------------------------------------------------------------

POST http://www.mywebsite.com/Service1.asmx HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 2.0.50727.4927)
VsDebuggerCausalityData: uIDPo+drc57U77xGu/ZaOdYvw6IAAAAA8AjKQNpkV06FEWDEs2Oja2C+h3kM7dlDvnFfE1VlIIIACQAA
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://www.mywebsite.com/HelloWorld"
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjE6cEBzc3cwcmQ=
Host: www.mywebsite.com
Content-Length: 291
Expect: 100-continue

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 

xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><HelloWorld xmlns="http://www.mywebsite.com/" /></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="www.mywebsite.com"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 03 Jun 2012 07:14:41 GMT
Content-Length: 1293
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Are you sure it's never run? Have you put a breakpoint into confirm this?

Comment: Yes I sure. Always `else` block is runs

Comment: Also have a look at what your Service1 class actually is doing. And see what's being transmitted  on the wire using a tool like fiddler.

Comment: I added also fiddler result into question.

Comment: What about the the client messages. You need to debug this in the following way. 1. Determine if the client is send the credentials. 2 Determine if the server is receiving them. 3. If these are all correct then you need to debug your code and the IIS server to see what happens to the HTTP request.  You need to establish all the basics first.

Comment: Is this APIKey validation check performed with each client request ,or just general validation check is performed

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change your custom HttpModule code to this:

```c#
public class BasicAuthHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.AuthenticateRequest += new 
            EventHandler(this.OnAuthenticateRequest);
        application.EndRequest += new 
            EventHandler(this.OnEndRequest);
    }

    public void OnAuthenticateRequest(object source, EventArgs
                        eventArgs)
    {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)source;

        string authHeader = app.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authHeader))
        {
            string authStr = app.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

            if (authStr == null || authStr.Length == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            authStr = authStr.Trim();
            if (authStr.IndexOf("Basic", 0) != 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            authStr = authStr.Trim();

            string encodedCredentials = authStr.Substring(6);

            byte[] decodedBytes =
            Convert.FromBase64String(encodedCredentials);
            string s = new ASCIIEncoding().GetString(decodedBytes);

            string[] userPass = s.Split(new char[] { ':' });
            string username = userPass[0];
            string password = userPass[1];

            if (!MyUserValidator.Validate(username, password))
            {
                DenyAccess(app);
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            app.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            app.Response.End();
        }
    }
    public void OnEndRequest(object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode == 401)
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            context.Response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic Realm");
        }
    }

    private void DenyAccess(HttpApplication app)
    {
        app.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        app.Response.StatusDescription = "Access Denied";
        app.Response.Write("401 Access Denied");
        app.CompleteRequest();
    }
}
```

Then enable `Anonymous authentication` and disable `Basic`, `Digest` and `Windows` authentication for your website in IIS.

**Note:** This implementation will work with WCF too.

Comment: In my case I also had to disable Anonymous authentication too.

`<security>
      <authentication>
        <digestAuthentication enabled="false"/>
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
        <basicAuthentication enabled="false"/>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
...`

Comment: For me it is only working in an application pool which uses the "Integrated application pool mode" - not working in classic mode. But I can't explain why exactly...

Comment: Worked for me... I did have to edit the web.config section. change type from  type="AuthService.BasicAuthHttpModule, AuthService" to type ="BasicAuthHttpModule".   I made sure the class I added BasicAuthHttpModule does not contain a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need send the headers manually the first time:

from [Rick Strahl's Blog](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2010/Feb/18/NET-WebRequestPreAuthenticate-not-quite-what-it-sounds-like)

```
    string url = "http://rasnote/wconnect/admin/wc.wc?_maintain~ShowStatus";
    HttpWebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

    string user = "ricks";
    string pwd = "secret";
    string domain = "www.west-wind.com";

    string auth = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(user + ":" + pwd));
    req.PreAuthenticate = true;
    req.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);
    req.UserAgent = ": Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3 (.NET CLR 4.0.20506)";
    WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    resp.Close();
```

Comment: I use this code and it also gives authentication error on `WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();`

Comment: Did you follow the rest of the article about preauthenticate?