# Server was unable to process request. ---> The authorization header is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

i use asmx web service with .net framework 2.0 , i use this code to call service

```
try
            {
                edu.sharif.hokm.Employee em = new edu.sharif.hokm.Employee();

                CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
                NetworkCredential credentials = new
                   NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
                credentialCache.Add(new Uri(em.Url),
                                    "Basic", credentials);
                em.Credentials = credentialCache;
                em.PreAuthenticate = true;

                DataTable dt = em.GetEmployee("1000");

                MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

but get this error

```
Server was unable to process request. ---> The authorization header is empty
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asmx web service basic authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861568/asmx-web-service-basic-authentication)

Comment: i use winform application

Comment: new Uri(em.Url) => does the em.Url have a proper value at that point?
Try with hard coded URL:
myCache.Add(new Uri("http://www.something.com/"),"Basic",new NetworkCredential(UserName,SecurelyStoredPassword));

Comment: Not work correctly